# Jquery script is not working for multiple data under multiple value

Tags: jquery

I have to created one table row that i have to make multiple dynamically and under that one row one more row will come that will be also multiple.

I have created a table structure and added jquery but that is only working for first main table row. Also I have to add industry_type_master_id on each Product_applications_id.

I need this type of result:

```
    [product_industry_applications] => Array
       (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [industry_type_master_id] => 1
            [Product_applications_id] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [industry_type_master_id] => 1
            [Product_applications_id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [industry_type_master_id] => 1
            [Product_applications_id] => 4
        )

)
```

////code

```
<div>
    <!--<label>Industry Type</label>-->
    <table style='border:thin solid gray;width:100%' class="industrytypeTable">

        <tr class="nRow">
            <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('product_industry_applications.n.industry_type_master_id', array('div'=>false,'label' => false,'empty'=>'Select Industry Type','style'=>'float:left','options'=>$groups)); ?>
        </td>
            <td>

        <table style='border:thin solid gray;width:100%' class="industrytypeTables">
        <tr class="nRows">
            <td><?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('product_industry_applications.ns.industry_type_master_id', array('type'=>"hidden"));
            echo $this->Form->input('product_industry_applications.ns.Product_applications_id', array('label' => false,'empty'=>'Select Application','style'=>'float:left','options'=>$subgroups)); ?>
            </td>
            <td class="actions" style='text-align:left'><a class="removers fa fa-minus fa-fw" ></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="addActionRows">
            <td></td>
            <td class="actions"  style='text-align:left'>
                <a class="addRows fa fa-plus fa-fw"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        </table>

            <?php //echo $this->Form->input('product_industry_applications.n.Product_applications_id', array('label' => false,'empty'=>'Select Application','style'=>'float:left','options'=>$subgroups)); ?>
            </td>
            <td class="actions" style='text-align:left'><a class="remover fa fa-minus fa-fw" ></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="addActionRow">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="actions"  style='text-align:left'>
                <a class="addRow fa fa-plus fa-fw"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>



    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     // industry type
     var testSpecificationTable=$('.industrytypeTable');
     var addRowHtml=$(testSpecificationTable).find(".nRow")[0].outerHTML;
     $(testSpecificationTable).find(".nRow").remove();
     var count=0;
     var rowEvent=function(elmt){
    $(elmt).each(function(){
    var _this=this;
    $(this).find(".remover").click(function(){
        $(_this).remove();
    });
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $(_this).find("td").css("background-color","lightgray");
    },function(){
        $(_this).find("td").css("background-color","transparent");
    });
      $(this).find("td").css("border-bottom","thin solid gray");
     });
    };
   $(testSpecificationTable).find(".addActionRow .addRow").click(function(){
   var elmt= 

$(addRowHtml).insertBefore($(testSpecificationTable).find(".addActionRow"));
$(elmt).find("input,textarea,select").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("name",$(this).attr("name").replace("[n]","["+count+"]"));     
});
rowEvent(elmt);
count++;            
 });
$(testSpecificationTable).find(".addActionRow .addRow").click();

   //application
   var testSpecificationTables=$('.industrytypeTables');
    var addRowHtmls=$(testSpecificationTables).find(".nRows")[0].outerHTML;
   $(testSpecificationTables).find(".nRows").remove();
   var counts=0;
   var rowEvents=function(elmt){
   $(elmt).each(function(){
    var _this=this;
    $(this).find(".removers").click(function(){
        $(_this).remove();
    });
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $(_this).find("td").css("background-color","lightgray");
    },function(){
        $(_this).find("td").css("background-color","transparent");
    });
    $(this).find("td").css("border-bottom","thin solid gray");
    });
    };
  $(testSpecificationTables).find(".addActionRows .addRows").click(function(){
var elmt= 


   $(addRowHtmls).insertBefore($(testSpecificationTables).
find(".addActionRows"));
      $(elmt).find("input,textarea,select").each(function() {
  $(this).attr("name",$(this).attr("name").replace("[ns]","["+counts+"]"));       
     });
     rowEvents(elmt);
    counts++;           
       });
     $(testSpecificationTables).find(".addActionRows .addRows").click();
```

Comment: Cant really understand the problem. I suggest you only include related codes and make a fiddle.